# How to download icons from any site

Tags: icons, website

How can I download the icon from any website like from the sign-in or any other icon? If I want the sign-in icon from [bbc.com](http://www.bbc.com/), how could I download it?

Comment: Please learn some basic browser commands. Right click > Save Image as works in Firefox. There are similar commands in other browsers.

Comment: I know this is a long shot but which browser are you using? You do have other options for [free website icons](http://fontawesome.io/icons/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you right click blank space on the page and click "Save As..." you will download all the page resources. You can see which pieces you're interested in keeping by using your browser's version of "View Source".

I'd urge you to learn some basic illustration tools to avoid using somebody else's resources without their permission.

Answer (score 9):

Just type the url (site) you want to download from in your default browser and add "/favicon.ico". So in your case:

[image]

Now you see the icon. You just have to right-click on it an save/ download it to your pc.

Comment: A favicon does not have to be at that location.  Even if its present, it may not be the one that is getting displayed.